# UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\x00' in position 8: invalid decimal Unicode string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

This line is giving me a `UnicodeEncodeError`

```
studentID = int(studentID.unicode_markup.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Specifically the error is this `UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\x00' in position 8: invalid decimal Unicode string`

If I change the line to this:

```
studentID = int(studentID.unicode_markup.encode('utf-8'))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0100\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0'
```

I have tried specifying a different encoding (like 'ascii') but it still gives me the same error.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you encoding and decoding the string when it's already unicode? All you need to do is pass in the string directly: i.e. `int(studentID.unicode_markup)`. The string has non-breaking spaces at the beginning and end, but `int()` will automatically strip those out.

Comment: int(studentID.unicode_markup) gives me the error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\x00' in position 8: invalid decimal Unicode string

Comment: The html document must contain null characters. Where are you getting this document from? Are you downloading it? And if so, how are you converting it into unicode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some non-visible characters in your string before and after the `100`. Therefore the`int` function is failing because it can't convert this string into an int.

Try the following approach to parse out any numbers before attempting to convert to int:

```
import re

# find all characters in the string that are numeric.
m = re.search(r'\d+', studentID.unicode_markup)
numeric = m.group() # retrieve numeric string
int(numeric) # returns 100
```

Comment: I now get this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @VishwaIyer - modifed to work for all cases where the string contains a number, and you want to extract that number to convert to int.

Comment: Probably this is the most reliable method. You don't need to encode the string to UTF-8 though, just use `m = re.search(r'\d+', studentID.unicode_markup)`

Comment: @VishwaIyer no problem. Just out of curiousity, was there any reason to encode the original string as `utf-8`? You should be able to run `re.search` on the original `unicode_markup` with the same result.

Comment: @MartinKonecny Honestly I don't know. I'm new to encoding and decoding and it's all really confusing for me. Your code worked after me spending hours trying to solve my problem. I really don't want to risk the code not working again.